# Is there any way to hide the JBOSS version when error message is thrown

Tags: jboss7.x

I want to know if there is any way to hide the JBOSS Version string when an error message is thrown. See the screenshot for reference.

[JBOSS_Error_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGE6f.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the JBoss error page by either adding your own application level error page by making an entry in web.xml -

```
<error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/Error404.html</location>
</error-page>
```

You can also do this using server side configuration as described here:
http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=1334

Comment: I added an entry in Web.xml as mentioned in the image but after the deployment it shows blank screen when the 404 error is thrown. I think I am not placing the Error404.html at correct location. Where should I place that html file so that after deployment it picks that.

Comment: in your WebContent folder